# Cannot get the selected item in a ListViewer in a JFace Dialog

Tags: jface, rcp

I created a dialog class that inherited from JFace Dialog using Windows Builder. In that, I added some controls included a button and a JFace ListViewer. In `widgetSelected()` function of the button, I can get out the selected item in the ListViewer. But in `okPressed(), I cannot get this. I don't know why. Can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access UI elements in `okPressed` you must do so before calling `super.okPressed()` because that will close the dialog and dispose of the controls. So something like:

```java
@Override
protected void okPressed()
{
  IStructuredSelection sel = viewer.getStructuredSelection();

  // TODO deal with selection

  // Call super.okPressed() last
  super.okPressed();
}
```

Alternatively save the selection when your `widgetSelected` is called.

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer.